# How to make div collapsible in ko template?

Tags: checkout, knockout, store-credit, collapsible

We often want to make store credit or adding gift card div collapsible on checkout page. How to make store credit or customer balance div collapsible in knockout template?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution what I found,
To add collapsible any div, we have to add three things.

1. `data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': '_active'}}` on the main div.
2. `data-role="title"` on the title div.
3. `data-role="content"` on the content div which we want to hide/show or collapse.

I have worked on customer balance (enterprise) template to make it collapsible on checkout page. Taken the main `customer-balance.html` ko template in the design folder and made following changes.

Find update template below

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko if: isAvailable && isActive() -->
<div class="payment-option opc-payment-additional customerbalance" id="customerbalance-placer"
     data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': '_active'}}">

     <div class="payment-option-title field choice" data-role="title">
        <span class="action action-toggle" id="block-customerbalance-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2">
            <!-- ko i18n: 'Store Credit' --><!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-option-content field choice" data-role="content">
        <div class="payment-option-inner">
            <span id="customerbalance-available-amount" data-bind="text: formatBalance()"></span>
            <!-- ko i18n: 'Store credit available' --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button id="use-customer-balance"
                        class="action action-use"
                        name="payment[use_customer_balance]"
                        data-bind="click: sendRequest">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Use Store Credit' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

- Added `data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': '_active'}}` on the main div.
- Added `data-role="title"` on the title div.
- Added `data-role="content"` on the content div.

Please make sure to add span `<span class="action action-toggle" ...>` to add collapsible icon.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,I have implemented and it worked.

Navigate to

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html

and have a look, then implement below in your custom module.

1.In the html file Add below to your div class, Particularly in that div where on click you want to show/hide/collapse which is coming from the above vendor path.

```
data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': isItemsBlockExpanded()}}"
```

2.In the title div, the class name must be title, otherwise it will not work.

```
e.g. class="title"
```

3.In the div where is content present to show, Add
data-role="content"

```
<div class="customer-content" data-role="content">
```

4. Use that isItemsBlockExpanded function in your js file as:

> ```
> isItemsBlockExpanded: function () {
>         return quote.isVirtual() || stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
>         }
> ```

Use the library or dependancy as:

> ```
> 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
> 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
> ```

and use stepNavigator, quote alias name as below in your js file:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, Component, stepNavigator, quote) {
    'use strict';
```

That's it ..  Thank You!!